# How to disable/skip advance welcome page on Ubuntu Server 14.04?

Tags: boot

On every reboot my system stops booting and asks me for a language. After that I have to choose boot form first hard drive.

The installation - ISO is not mounted.

Can anyone tell me how I can diable or skip this menu automatically on booting.

Picture 1:
[image]

Picture 2:
[image]

Comment: Well, your definitely booting off some installation media… Please double check that you aren't booting from it anywhere. Since your statements suggest that you are using a Virtual Machine, would you mind telling us which one and how you started installation? Sorry about the answer, I actually wanted to write a comment ^_^

Comment: Hi, yes I double checked, that I am not booting from the mounted ISO. Moreover, I change the boot order to "only Hard disk". And yes I am using a VM, which is running on a KVM hypervisor. It seems to me that the installation media was copied to the hard disk during the installation. Can you tell me how I can check this or remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The USB/CD from which the installation is made is still in the computer so it boots from there. Remove it.